# Numpy: How to turn an nx8 array into an nx4 array where odd columns are real and even ones are imaginary?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I tried the solutions from [Numpy: Creating a complex array from 2 real ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598734/numpy-creating-a-complex-array-from-2-real-ones) but can't seem to get them to work for an array with more than 2 columns.

I have code that works but is very inefficient. I couldn't imagine if the column numbers were much higher.

```
reTrc1_S22_thrutest = thrutest[:,0]
imTrc1_S22_thrutest = 1j*thrutest[:,1]

Trc1_S22_thrutest = reTrc1_S22_thrutest + imTrc1_S22_thrutest
```

Answer (score 0):

To get even columns or odd columns from a numpy array, you can use [slicing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198747/how-can-i-simultaneously-select-all-odd-rows-and-all-even-columns-of-an-array).

```
reTrc1_S22_thrutest = thrutest[:,0::2]
imTrc1_S22_thrutest = 1j*thrutest[:,1::2]

Trc1_S22_thrutest = reTrc1_S22_thrutest + imTrc1_S22_thrutest
```